# Grouping non-consecutive items in Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I'm trying to see if I can do a collapse (+/-) thing on Excel by grouping items together. However, I want to group items that are non-consecutive. Here's an example:

```
1: a
2: b
3: ac
4: be
5: ay
6: bi
7: ace
8: bye
```

I would want to group it by putting all of the items that start with "a" under "a" and the same with "b." Basically, I'd be grouping lines 3, 5, 7 under line 1 and the rest of the lines, except for line 2, under line 2. So, how do I go about this?

I've tried using the group option, but it won't let me group nonconsecutive rows together.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

Step 1 sort the data:
You will end up with

a
ac
ace
ay
b
be
bi
bye

Step 2 add a row between end of "a" data and start of "b" data

a
ac
ace
ay

b
be
bi
bye

Step 3 group rows 2-4 and then 7-9

Comment: It works! Now, I need to figure it out for more complex tasks, which is why I still want to find the question out